# Loading jQuery based javascript in Jupyter Notebook with RequireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs, jupyter-notebook

I am working in a Python 3 notebook. I downloaded this [jQuery Flight Indicators](https://github.com/sebmatton/jQuery-Flight-Indicators) project and it's saved in my notebooks directory. I'd like to be able to pass the pitch, roll, speed from python variables, and generate a plot in the notebook. Ideally I could also save an image of the dynamic plot.

But to start, I just want to get the dials loaded up in the notebook. I have an HTML cell:

```
%%HTML
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery-Flight-Indicators/css/flightindicators.css" />
<span id="attitude"></span>
```

And a javascript cell:

```
%%js
require.config({
  paths: {flightIndicator: "jQuery-Flight-Indicators\js\jquery.flightindicators.js"}
  });
require(["jquery", "jquery.flightindicators"], function( $, flightIndicator ){
var first_attitude = $.flightIndicator('#first_attitude', 'attitude', {size:350, roll:8, pitch:3, showBox : true});
});
```

When both cells are executed, nothing happens...